# Android XML FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have my XML file describing my landscape activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/img1"
        android:padding="24dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trueButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/falseButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next_button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:contentDescription="arrowLeft"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:contentDescription="arrowRight"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the pre and next ImageButtons underneath the trueButton and falseButton but I can't get it to work. I tried:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

But that has no effect on it whatsoever. I'm required to use a FrameLayout for this.

This is what it currently displays as when I run:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Katie

Comment: u need that button below true and false button >

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `FrameLayout` is the right tool for this job; its capabilities are relatively limited for arranging multiple children in relation to each other. You'd generally be better off using something like a `ConstraintLayout` to accomplish this.

If, however, `FrameLayout` is a requirement, then I think the only thing you can do is wrap both the true/false and the prev/next buttons in a vertical `LinearLayout`, and then center *that* in the `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button/>

            <Button/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button/>

            <Button/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a linear layout below your frameLayout

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/img1"
    android:padding="24dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/trueButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/falseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:contentDescription="arrowLeft"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:contentDescription="arrowRight"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/img1"
        android:padding="24dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/trueButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/true_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/falseButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/false_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/prev_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:contentDescription="arrowLeft"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:contentDescription="arrowRight"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**I am using frame layout like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="24dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="False" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="arrowLeft"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="arrowRight"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i am using this line to change gravity

**android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"**

like this:
[image]